# Kubuntu with RT3290 wi-ficard, after upgrade to 16.10, hanging on startup

Tags: wireless, startup, 16.10

Recently I've upgraded Kubuntu 15.10 to 16.10. The first run after the uprgrade went well, everything was working, exept the wi-fi driver for my RT3290 card, so I didn't have access to the net `(although the same driver with the same kernel does work when booted from the LiveDVD)`.

I've already had a similar problem after the 15.10 installation, so I knew I should find another driver, one that works. I've rebooted several times meanwhile `(since I had to boot from the LiveDVD in order to access the Internet)`, while looking for a driver and instructions, untill I found `RT3290_u16; it worked, so finally I was able to access the Internet and to install a lot of other software and updates. Basicaly, I've reinstalled`(almost)` all packages I've already I had under 15.10, since I had listed installed packages in dpkg prior to the upgrade. Among the updates I've also installed two new kernels :

```
4.8.0-26 and 4.8.0-27.
```

It was quite a long session and everything was working well. But, atfer the first reboot the startup hanged at certain point and every successive time it was hanging about the same point. The same thing was happening when I booted with

```
4.8.0-26 kernel and with 4.8.0-22 kernel
```

the kernel that originally came with Kubuntu 16.10 installation). But, when I booted with `4.2.0-36 (the kernel left from Kubuntu 15.10)`, it was going ahead normally and I was able to login to the desktop and have a normal session with only `misfortune` that there is `no rt2860sta module` there, nor could I reinstall it for that kernel, so I don't have access to the net.

When I boot from LiveDVD I can chroot, so I can add or remove packages, see logs etc. I've removed kernels  `4.8.0-26 and 4.8.0-27`, nothing changed. The last message on screen before the startup hanging was talking about

```
nfs ("Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel  transport module"),
```

so I did

```
"dpkg -l | grep nfs"
```

and removed nfs-kernel-server, I thought I had removed everythiing it catched, but, now I see there're `libfile-nfslock-perl, libnfsidmap2, nfs-common and unionfs-fuse installed` - it still hangs.

I've found out the following files were being `created or modified` during a startup till it hangs:

/var/log/ConsoleKit/history:

```
1478807647.561 type=SEAT_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' seat-kind=0
1478808144.049 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session1' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/pts/3' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=150 session-creation-time='2016-11-10T20:02:24.043989Z'
1478808147.096 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session1' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/pts/3' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=150 session-creation-time='2016-11-10T20:02:24.043989Z'
1478808205.919 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session2' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=33 session-creation-time='2016-11-10T20:03:25.915781Z'
1478808205.953 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session2' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=33 session-creation-time='2016-11-10T20:03:25.915781Z'
1478808228.851 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session3' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/pts/3' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=150 session-creation-time='2016-11-10T20:03:48.847396Z'
1478808252.600 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session3' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/pts/3' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=150 session-creation-time='2016-11-10T20:03:48.847396Z'
<and-so-on>
1478809134.998 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session11' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/pts/3' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=121 session-creation-time='2016-11-10T20:18:54.994117Z'
1478809183.811 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session11' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/pts/3' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=121 session-creation-time='2016-11-10T20:18:54.994117Z'
1478824038.496 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478824106.227 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478824549.760 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478824549.881 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478824549.908 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478831201.314 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro recovery nomodeset'
1478831223.277 type=SEAT_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' seat-kind=0
1478831224.820 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session4' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/tty9' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T02:27:04.814552Z'
<and-so-on>
1478831248.141 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session18' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T02:27:28.137347Z'
1478831248.864 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session18' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T02:27:28.137347Z'
1478831283.047 type=SEAT_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' seat-kind=0
1478831283.078 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session4' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T02:28:03.074637Z'
1478831283.078 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session3' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display
<and-so-on>
1478831528.225 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session5' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=33 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T02:32:08.221149Z'
1478831528.276 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session5' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=33 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T02:32:08.221149Z'
1478831748.782 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478832278.199 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478832278.374 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478832278.397 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478834546.330 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro recovery nomodeset'
1478834573.673 type=SEAT_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' seat-kind=0
1478834574.561 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session5' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T03:22:54.555623Z'
1478834574.561 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session4' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display
<and-so-on>
1478834594.121 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session2' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/tty9' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T03:22:54.546519Z'
1478834631.872 type=SEAT_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' seat-kind=0
1478834631.904 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session4' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T03:23:51.899435Z'
<and-so-on>
1478834632.008 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session3' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T03:23:51.897770Z'
1478837164.009 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-26-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478884875.358 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478887354.879 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478892119.538 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478892175.260 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478892238.232 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='placeholder root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478892272.612 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478892688.053 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-22-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478892805.388 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478892849.487 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.2.0-36-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478892876.747 type=SEAT_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' seat-kind=0
1478892878.019 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session5' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/tty9' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T19:34:38.010480Z'
<and-so-on>
1478892900.750 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session5' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/tty9' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T19:34:38.010480Z'
1478892973.563 type=SEAT_ADDED : seat-id='Seat2' seat-kind=1
1478892973.565 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat2' session-id='Session6' session-type='' session-x11-display=':0' session-x11-display-device='/dev/tty7' session-display-device='' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=FALSE session-unix-user=1000 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T19:36:13.561260Z'
1478894913.812 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat2' session-id='Session6' session-type='' session-x11-display=':0' session-x11-display-device='/dev/tty7' session-display-device='' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=FALSE session-unix-user=1000 session-creation-time='2016-11-11T19:36:13.561260Z'
1478894948.607 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478895000.808 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-22-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478895165.344 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478895165.543 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478895165.570 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478899659.853 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478899705.845 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478900576.755 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478902322.812 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478902323.016 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478902323.045 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478905241.971 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478905485.331 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478905485.481 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478905485.509 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478922764.871 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478925138.362 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478925138.545 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478925138.571 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478925138.646 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478925293.125 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478925401.620 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478925401.821 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478925401.845 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478959185.667 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478959537.564 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478959537.787 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478959537.797 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478960611.449 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478960832.222 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478964033.452 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478970518.109 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478970518.297 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478970518.320 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478994853.428 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1478995420.765 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478995420.825 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478995420.848 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1478995420.913 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479000616.347 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1479000661.865 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479000662.009 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479000662.034 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479000771.595 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.2.0-36-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-36-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1479000796.969 type=SEAT_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' seat-kind=0
1479000799.119 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session4' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=154 session-creation-time='2016-11-13T01:33:19.111920Z'
<and-so-on>
1479000891.377 type=SEAT_ADDED : seat-id='Seat2' seat-kind=1
1479000891.379 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat2' session-id='Session6' session-type='' session-x11-display=':0' session-x11-display-device='/dev/tty7' session-display-device='' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=FALSE session-unix-user=1000 session-creation-time='2016-11-13T01:34:51.373637Z'
1479001303.442 type=SEAT_SESSION_ADDED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session7' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=33 session-creation-time='2016-11-13T01:41:43.437501Z'
1479001303.490 type=SEAT_SESSION_REMOVED : seat-id='Seat1' session-id='Session7' session-type='' session-x11-display='' session-x11-display-device='' session-display-device='/dev/???' session-remote-host-name='' session-is-local=TRUE session-unix-user=33 session-creation-time='2016-11-13T01:41:43.437501Z'
1479035385.782 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479035423.971 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1479040647.353 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479040647.611 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479040647.620 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479040647.727 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479040647.742 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479048186.771 type=SYSTEM_START : kernel-release='4.8.0-27-generic' boot-arguments='BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic root=UUID=291f6c9c-b6c7-4c29-9eb7-94fc66158949 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 panic=-1'
1479048590.838 type=SYSTEM_RESTART : 
1479048591.090 type=SYSTEM_RESTART :
```

/var/log/macchanger.log:

```
disabled in /etc/default/macchanger
disabled in /etc/default/macchanger
disabled in /etc/default/macchanger
disabled in /etc/default/macchanger
disabled in /etc/default/macchanger
disabled in /etc/default/macchanger
disabled in /etc/default/macchanger
```

/var/cache/openafs-client/openafs-client.env:
(N.B. Meanwhile I've removed openafs-client - without effect)

```
AFSD_ARGS= -afsdb -dynroot -fakestat
AFS_SETCRYPT=on
AFS_SYSNAME=-help
KMOD=openafs
```

/var/lib/whereami/whereiam.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$DEBUGWHEREAMI" = "1" ] && set -o xtrace
LASTLOCN=if-pre-up,--all; export LASTLOCN
LOCATION=ra0,if-pre-up; export LOCATION

GATEWAY=""
PROXY="none"
NTPDAEMON=/etc/init.d/ntp-server
NTPSERVER=ntp
```

/var/lib/whereami/iam:

```
ra0
if-pre-up

/var/lib/whereami/iwas:

if-pre-up
--all
```

/var/lib/whereami/dhclient.ra0:

```
# Generated by /sbin/dhclient-script - do not edit!
reason=PREINIT
new_ip_address=
alias_ip_address=
interface=ra0
medium=
new_subnet_mask=
```

(Strange, but, there're no /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/syslog among files modified during that startup.) There're also two binary files: /var/lib/systemd/random-seed and /var/log/wtmp Here is the output of `last -f /var/log/wtmp :

```
`<my_username>       pts/1        :0               Mon Nov 14 23:34 - 00:56  (01:22)
<my_username>       pts/2        :0               Mon Nov 14 23:34 - 00:56  (01:22)
<my_username>       pts/3        :0               Mon Nov 14 23:34 - 00:56  (01:22)
<my_username>       pts/0        :0               Mon Nov 14 23:33 - 00:56  (01:22)
reboot   system boot  4.2.0-36-generic Mon Nov 14 23:31 - 00:57  (01:26)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-22-generic Mon Nov 14 02:41 - 02:44  (00:02)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-22-generic Mon Nov 14 02:27 - 02:28  (00:01)
<my_username>       pts/3        :0               Mon Nov 14 02:08 - 02:19  (00:11)
<my_username>       pts/0        :0               Mon Nov 14 02:08 - 02:19  (00:11)
<my_username>       pts/2        :0               Mon Nov 14 02:08 - 02:19  (00:11)
<my_username>       pts/1        :0               Mon Nov 14 02:08 - 02:19  (00:11)
reboot   system boot  4.2.0-36-generic Mon Nov 14 02:05 - 02:19  (00:13)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-22-generic Mon Nov 14 01:01 - 02:19  (01:18)
<my_username>       pts/3        :0               Sun Nov 13 23:26 - 00:07  (00:41)
<my_username>       pts/2        :0               Sun Nov 13 23:26 - 00:07  (00:41)
<my_username>       pts/1        :0               Sun Nov 13 23:26 - 00:07  (00:41)
<my_username>       pts/0        :0               Sun Nov 13 23:26 - down   (00:41)
reboot   system boot  4.2.0-36-generic Sun Nov 13 23:23 - 00:08  (00:44)
<etc 10 times>
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-27-generic Sun Nov 13 12:10 - 13:37  (01:27)
<my_username>       pts/3        :0               Sun Nov 13 02:35 - crash  (09:34)
<my_username>       pts/2        :0               Sun Nov 13 02:35 - crash  (09:34)
<my_username>       pts/0        :0               Sun Nov 13 02:35 - crash  (09:34)
<my_username>       pts/1        :0               Sun Nov 13 02:35 - crash  (09:34)
reboot   system boot  4.2.0-36-generic Sun Nov 13 02:32 - 13:37  (11:04)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-27-generic Sun Nov 13 02:30 - 02:31  (00:00)
<etc 10 times>
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-27-generic Sat Nov 12 16:20 - 18:08  (01:48)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-22-generic Fri Nov 11 21:09 - 21:12  (00:02)
<my_username>       pts/1        :0               Fri Nov 11 20:37 - 21:08  (00:31)
<my_username>       pts/3        :0               Fri Nov 11 20:37 - 21:08  (00:31)
<my_username>       pts/2        :0               Fri Nov 11 20:37 - 21:08  (00:31)
<my_username>       pts/0        :0               Fri Nov 11 20:37 - crash  (00:32)
reboot   system boot  4.2.0-36-generic Fri Nov 11 20:33 - 21:12  (00:38)
<etc 10 times>
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-27-generic Fri Nov 11 01:28 - 01:35  (00:07)
<my_username>       pts/3        :0               Thu Nov 10 23:13 - 01:26  (02:12)
<etc 10 times>
<my_username>       pts/0        :0               Wed Nov  9 23:39 - 01:26 (1+01:46)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-22-generic Wed Nov  9 23:38 - 01:27 (1+01:48)
<my_username>       pts/3        :0               Wed Nov  9 23:24 - 23:30  (00:05)
<my_username>       pts/2        :0               Wed Nov  9 23:24 - 23:38  (00:13)
<my_username>       pts/1        :0               Wed Nov  9 23:19 - down   (00:18)
<my_username>       pts/0        :0               Wed Nov  9 23:19 - 23:38  (00:18)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-22-generic Wed Nov  9 23:18 - 23:38  (00:19)
<my_username>       pts/1        :0               Wed Nov  9 22:32 - 23:04  (00:31)
<my_username>       pts/0        :0               Wed Nov  9 22:32 - 23:04  (00:31)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-22-generic Wed Nov  9 22:31 - 23:04  (00:33)
<my_username>       pts/1        :0               Wed Nov  9 02:03 - 19:56  (17:52)
<my_username>       pts/0        :0               Wed Nov  9 01:52 - 19:56  (18:03)
reboot   system boot  4.8.0-22-generic Wed Nov  9 01:49 - 23:04  (21:14)

wtmp begins Wed Nov  9 01:49:58 2016
```

and here is what dmesg sais:

```
[1576780.312358] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
<many times>
[1584025.169734] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[1584026.589753] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
<many times>
[1584070.465011] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[1584071.673494] wlo1: authenticate with 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca
[1584071.884994] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[1584071.897090] wlo1: send auth to 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca (try 1/3)
[1584071.898748] wlo1: authenticated
[1584071.905042] wlo1: associate with 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca (try 1/3)
[1584071.909105] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[1584071.909189] wlo1: associated
[1584071.909232] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[1584073.552214] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 10h 8min 15.842213s random time.
[1584073.749582] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 10h 55min 8.293527s random time.
[1584087.952747] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
<many times>
[1584137.291997] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[1584507.922339] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
<many times>
[1585093.983061] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[1585093.999128] wlo1: deauthenticating from 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[1585642.343913] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3290, rev 0015 detected
[1585642.347629] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 3290 detected
[1585642.348451] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[1585642.411309] rt2800pci 0000:04:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[1585642.443913] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[1585642.443974] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[1585642.460842] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
[1585642.535662] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[1585642.604812] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[1585653.262782] wlo1: authenticate with 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca
[1585653.286404] wlo1: send auth to 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca (try 1/3)
[1585653.288119] wlo1: authenticated
[1585653.290315] wlo1: associate with 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca (try 1/3)
[1585653.296200] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[1585653.296289] wlo1: associated
[1585653.296339] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[1585654.744833] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 7h 15min 28.992698s random time.
[1585654.977579] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 2h 18min 56.759857s random time.
[1585670.048516] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
<many times>
[1586079.097931] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[1589201.873082] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[1591824.745346] wlo1: deauthenticating from 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[1591843.093193] wlo1: authenticate with 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca
[1591843.116931] wlo1: send auth to 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca (try 1/3)
[1591843.118575] wlo1: authenticated
[1591843.120830] wlo1: associate with 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca (try 1/3)
[1591843.124667] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 8c:79:67:42:9e:ca (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[1591843.124752] wlo1: associated
[1591844.766897] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 8h 54min 17.789359s random time.
[1591844.971226] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 3h 28min 40.817774s random time.
[1591851.980718] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
<many times>
[1591857.392612] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[1592280.552384] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp5s0: link is not ready
[1592280.890090] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 2h 37min 6.964216s random time.
[1640190.461559] kpat[11514]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f343df09a67 sp 00007fff7c357150 error 4 in libKF5CoreAddons.so.5.26.0[7f343de9e000+8f000]
[1667862.769254] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
<many times>
[1714547.192723] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
```

I strongly suspect, I'm almost sure that the startup is being blocked by something asking to go to the Internet and the reason why it can't do it at that moment is my wi-fi connection that is password protected. But, I can't figure out what it could be, nor I have idea how to find it out and how to make it calm and patient (or at least to remove it, if neccessary). Please, did anybody have similar experiences, or does somebody understand something from the listings above?